# Weird behaviour of django dynamic url

Tags: python, regex, django, dynamic-url

I use  dynamic URLs in django. It works fine for integer values, and works for strings if the dynamic part is the end if the URL. When there is  some other component in the URL after the dynamic variable, say:

```
url(r'companies/(?P<comp_id>.+)/buy/?$',views.buy)
```

Now in the views.buy function,

```
print comp_id
```

gives me `id1/buy`. So, it takes the whole of the remaining URL as the comp_id variable. How do I stop it?

company.html:

```
<html>
    <head>
            <title>{{ company.name }}</title>
    </head>
    <body>
            Name:{{ company.name }}<br> 
            Worth: {{ company.company_worth }}<br>

            <form action="/companies/{{ company.comp_id }}/buy/" method = "post">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    {{ form.as_p }}
                    <input type="submit" value="Buy">
            </form>

    </body>
```

Comment: That would not be possible; you'd have to have a url like `companies/id1/buy/buy` for that to happen.

Comment: In any case, you can match `[^/]+` to match any character that is *not* a slash instead of `.+`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: `(?P<comp_id>[^/]+)` doesn't work either

Comment: Could you show other URLs? Do you have `companies/...` also mapped to `view.buy`?

Comment: @SimeonVisser: No. Only this URL is mapped to views.buy

Comment: @AswinMurugesh: Define "doesn't work". If you still see `id1/buy` then you have a *different* route to the same view, because that pattern cannot match `/`. At all. Check for a `companies/(?P<comp_id>.+` rule elsewhere.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: `url(r'companies/(?P<comp_id>.+)/$',views.company_details)` this works fine`

Comment: @MartijnPieters: By doesn't work I mean that it throws an error for unable to retrive company with the given id. (DoesNotExist) exception

Comment: @AswinMurugesh: Yes, and *that* pattern is matching `id1/buy`, not the one you posted in your question.

Comment: @AswinMurugesh: And what did `comp_id` match in that case then? You need to provide us with some detail here, not just tell us "it doesn't work" and expect us to guess your whole application structure from that.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: The Company object is retrived in the company_details view, and the details about the company is displayed in company.html page, shown in the question. The URL buy is called from there.

Comment: `url(r'companies/(?P<comp_id>.+?)/buy(/|)$', views.buy)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `comp_id` value is `id1`, this would do the trick.

```
url(r'companies/(?P<pdf>\w+)/buy/?$',views.buy)
```

Comment: I may have `_` in the id too. Eg) id_1

Comment: @AswinMurugesh: No problem. `\w` matches alphanumeric characters, including "_", same as [A-Za-z0-9_]

Answer (score 1):

```
url(r'companies/(?P<comp_id>.+?)/buy(/|)$', views.buy)
```